# Divide By Zero - Can't see why this would fail

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written a function just to work out the Pro-Rata Clawback on any amount me typing it out constantly.

However I get a Divide By Zero Error everytime it runs, I broke the function down very simply.

```
DECLARE @ProRataAmount DECIMAL(8,2), @DaysRemaining INT,@NetValue DECIMAL(8,2), @TimeOnRisk INTEGER

SET @NetValue = 29.00
SET @TimeOnRisk = 8

SET @DaysRemaining = (365 - @TimeOnRisk)

PRINT @DaysRemaining
PRINT @NetValue

SELECT @NetValue / (@DaysRemaining/365)
```

There is NO value there that is dividing by zero, so why is it returning said error?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An INT/INT will return an INT.

Try the following  (notice the 365.0):

```
SELECT @NetValue / (@DaysRemaining/365.0)
```

Now, just in case @DaysRemaining is ZERO, you can still generate a Divide By Zero unless you trap it like so:

```
SELECT @NetValue / (NullIf(@DaysRemaining,0)/365.0)
```

Comment: Occum <gesundheit!>

Comment: @xQbert OK that was funny  :)

Comment: I don't know it just seemed to fit, and I was being quirky.

Comment: @xQbert I got it.  Humor is a sign of intelligence.  I keep telling my wife that, but she's not buying it.

Comment: Just have to reward your elegant and simple answers.  Sometimes w/ upvotes. sometimes with quirky humor.

Answer (score -1):

Dividing an integer with an integer will cause the problem here:

```
SELECT @NetValue / (@DaysRemaining/365)
```

Here you will always divide by zero because `@DaysRemaining` is less than the divisor. You can change the calculation around to get past this easily while keeping the value as integer:

```
SELECT @NetValue * 365 / @DaysRemaining
```

Comment: Assuming the downvoter didn't think maths works that way but it does. This keeps the values as ints if that is desired.